# Relativistic Velocity

Tags: quantum-mechanics, special-relativity, energy, wavefunction, mass-energy

As a particle has enough relativistic
velocity, it’s mass should have a noticeable increase. How does this translate into the particle’s wave function? Is there a difference between an elementary particle’s wave function and a composite one?

Comment: Velocity-dependent “relativistic mass” is an obsolete concept. In modern physics, “mass” means “Lorentz-invariant mass”, which is independent of velocity.

Comment: @G.Smith I don't think that solves the question of what happens to a particle's wave function. Are you saying the wave function depends only on the invariant mass, and is not affected by velocity?

Comment: @electronpusher I was simply pointing out that the first sentence of the question is a false premise. I was not trying to answer the question, which I think lacks focus. The Dirac equation is fully relativistic; it describes the wavefunction of an electron moving with *any* velocity, and the mass in it is the Lorentz-invariant mass. (The Schrodinger equation is non-relativistic.) Relativistic quantum field theories such as QED deal only with the Lorentz-invariant mass.

Answer (score 1):

(1) Relativistic mass is passé. It had been relegated to the ash heap of history, but it appears internet science education has brought it back from the dead.

(2) Single particle wave functions are the realm of quantum mechanics, which is strictly non-relativistic. (Any confined wave function will have arbitrary large momentum components that are not confined to the light cone).

The solution is quantum field theory, which is a vast subject.

Whether an elementary particle's wave function differs from a composite particle's wave function is a question of scale. If one were to solve a particle in box, the solution would be the same for an atom or an electron, unless the box were smaller than an atom.

Comment: Pardon my ignorance; are you saying that as a particle’s velocity increases, it’s mass doesn’t increase? Perhaps I wasn’t clear enough, but when I meant mass I am still classifying it under electron-volt’s, not kilograms.

Comment: @Evamentality $E^2 = (pc)^2 + (mc^2)^2= (\gamma mc^2)^2$ in eV or kg.